# Exercício com scanner em curso, não executa corretamente

Tags: java, if, else, scanner

Estou estudando em um curso de desenvolvimento de games usando *Java*, em uma das aulas é proposto um exercício usando *scanner*,porém ao tentar executar o código não executa corretamente.
o código em questão esta abaixo, a parte que não executa corretamente é após **''você deseja avançar para qual direção''**.
quando executo, mesmo apertando *w*, não aparece **" você está indo pra frente"**.
Quando mudo a parte `if(comando == "w")` para `if (comando != "w")` ele executa essa parte corretamente porem não as outras.
Alguém poderia ajudar a encontrar o erro por favor? Obs: uso programa eclipse.

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nome;
    Random rand = new Random();
/*rand.nextInt(100);*/
    System.out.println("Seja bem-vindo ao jogo, Diga o seu nome: ");
    nome = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Seja muito bem-vindo(a) " + nome );
    System.out.println("Você deseja avançar para qual direção? w , s , a ,d ");
    String comando = in.nextLine();
    if (comando == "w") {
        System.out.println("Você está indo para frente! ");
        System.out.println("Um inimigo apareceu, o que deseja fazer? (a=atacar, c=correr ?");
        comando = in.nextLine();
        if (comando =="a") {
            if(rand.nextInt(100) < 75) {
                System.out.println("Você ganhou o jogo! "); 
            } else { System.out.println("você perdeu o jogo ");
            
            }
        }else { System.out.println("Você fugiu!, o jogo terminou");
        } 
        }else if (comando =="s") { 
            System.out.println("Você tem certeza que deseja voltar? ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Em Java, `==` representa comparação por identidade (se duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo objeto na memória) e `.equals()` representa comparação por igualdade (se duas variáveis apontam para dois objetos com propriedades iguais). Neste caso, você deseja utilizar a comparação por igualdade, substituindo

```java
if (comando == "w")
```

por

```java
if (comando.equals("w"))
```